# Where to ask certain questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have recently been informed that is frowned upon to ask if anyone knows a part that would work in your circuit. What I need, is a part. I have done digging, I can't find what I'm looking for.

Since it is bad form, I will not ask that sort of question here. What I would like to know, is if anyone knows of a place where I can ask that sort of question. (Another forum, something.)

Comment: You can ask that in [our EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering), where rules are more relaxed.

Comment: The _chat_ ? Where's that?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure lots of people know where you can ask that kind of question.

Comment: With chat as below you'll need a reputation of 20 to participate but stick with it a while and you should get there soon enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are types of questions that are one or more of the following: killed on sight, frowned upon, not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A format.

One can try his luck with such question in the EE.SE chat, where rules are more relaxed.

The link to the chat is through the StackExchange menu.

[image]

Comment: I'd add that you need 20 rep to do this... also, be nice and respectful. The people in the room are not required to help you and they may get really annoyed when you start pinging everyone in the room to see if they know the answer.

Comment: Serious question, and don't get mad: Why is that the standard? Honestly, I don't think I could EVER use this site for asking about theory. No offense, but my work problems are all under NDA, and I don't trust you :). The only thing I COULD use this site for is for help with the meta problems in our profession: finding parts, suggesting tools, suggesting fabs, doing operations (planning for lead times), talking to sales reps, etc. All those things are instantly banned. Why ISN'T there a place for this (like the "programmers" stack exchange, only for electrical engineers)?

Comment: @yhyrcanus  (1) Some of the rationale as to why shopping questions are off-topic [can be found here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  (2) If you are under an NDA, that's your problem for which you are being paid, I hope. 
(3) At the moment of writing, you don't seem to have an account on Programmers.SE, so you probably don't have first hand experience with that stack.  Programmers.SE is as vicious and clean as EE.SE, if not more so.  [My kind of stack.]